ARP command missing
I got this message trying to use arp:
Name:~$ arp
Command 'arp' not found, did you mean:
  command 'ark' from snap ark (24.08.0)
  command 'warp' from deb libghc-wai-app-static-dev (3.1.8-1)
  command 'art' from deb artemis (18.2.0+dfsg-3)
  command 'arj' from deb arj (3.10.22-26)
  command 'avrp' from deb avrp (1.0beta3-7build1)
  command 'ark' from deb ark (4:23.08.4-0ubuntu1)
  command 'ara' from deb python3-ara (1.5.8-1.1ubuntu1)
  command 'arc' from deb arc (5.21q-12)
See 'snap info <snapname>' for additional versions.

Arp installation instructions here
Give this result:
Name:~$ sudo apt-get install net-tools
[sudo] password for user: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package net-tools is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

What is the problem and how do I add ARP?

That's odd - net-tools is certainly available for 24.04 and it's in the noble/main repository. Please check you have the main component in your sources and then run sudo apt update.
